# Script in cron.hourly does not run

Tags: scripts, cron

I have the following file in `/etc/cron.hourly`. The purpose of this script is to create a docker-MongoDB dump backup every hour and then use rclone to synchronize this dump file with the contents in a Google Drive folder.

Name of Script:

```
rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/docker exec -it mongodb mkdir /data/dump
/usr/bin/docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --db myDB -u theUser -p thePassword --gzip --out /data/dump/

# RClone Config file
RCLONE_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/.config/rclone/rclone.conf
export RCLONE_CONFIG
#if [[ "`pidof -x $(basename $0) -o %PPID`" ]]; then exit; fi

/usr/bin/rclone sync /data/dump/myDB/MongoDB_Backup:MongoDB_Current
```

I have done:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
sudo chmod 777 /etc/cron.hourly/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
```

Notice how I do not have the `.sh` extension for the script. Previously, this was my issue. Now, when I run the following, my script does display.

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

My script also runs correctly when I do:

```
./rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
```

It also runs when I do:

```
run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

I have checked /etc/crontab with:

```
cat /etc/crontab
```

Part of the result is the following. To my understanding, this is correct.

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I evaluated the logs for cron with the following:

```
 grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

For the daily, weekly, and monthly, I believe they previously were not working due to anacron not being installed. I installed anacron with:

```
sudo apt-get install anacron
```

cron.hourly runs at the 17 minute mark of the hour, as indicated by `/etc/crontab`. Corresponding to this, I see the following repeated each time, with a 17 timestamp.

```
Jul 19 17:17:01 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1039453]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 19 17:17:09 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1039452]: (root) MAIL (mailed 104 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Jul 19 18:17:01 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1045250]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 19 18:17:18 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1045249]: (root) MAIL (mailed 104 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Jul 19 19:17:01 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1051174]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 19 19:17:21 vps-fac5a33c CRON[1051173]: (root) MAIL (mailed 104 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

Perhaps there are some things that I have done that I have forgotten about and not listed here. Nevertheless, I don't understand why this is not working. I have evaluated many different forum posts, tried their process, but doesn't work for me.

Why is my script not running every hour when it is placed in `/etc/cron.hourly`?

It does not run on its own. It should run every hour.

As an additional note, my script previously had:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

However, based on some posts, I changed it to:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

When I run `shellcheck` on my script, nothing is displayed, indicating that it is fine according to `shellcheck` and is syntactically correct:

```
shellcheck rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
```

Added the following to the top of the script after `#!/bin/sh`. This is to see what errors are occurring within the script during execution.

```
exec 1>>/tmp/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync.log 2>&1
```

I changed the crontab for .hourly to a recent time to not have to wait until the 17 minute mark for it to run. Due to the above addition to my script file, the following file was created:

```
/tmp/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync.log
```

After running:

```
 cat /tmp/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync.log
```

The following was displayed.

```
the input device is not a TTY
the input device is not a TTY
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: 1) If `shellcheck` does not display anything, it means that the script is syntactically correct. 2) Please never use `chmod 777` to make scripts world-writable (`755` is enough, `u+rx` is minimum requirement). 3) The part regarding daily/weekly/monthly tasks can be stripped, it's unrelated (and anacron is _not_ needed here; the test says "execute the right-hand command only if anacron is not found and executable, in which case the latter takes care of this!) 4) Are you sure that your problem persists?

Comment: btw if you ever uncomment `#if [[` you will need to switch the shebang back to `#!/bin/bash` since POSIX sh doesn't support the ksh-style `[[...]]` extended test

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. I will keep that in mind and also apply what you mentioned to my script

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer to include what is now being displayed in the logs.

Comment: Sure will do, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it appears this is an issue with `Docker`. When issuing commands in `Docker` through `cron`, instead of `-it` only use `-i`. I have now changed my `Docker` commands accordingly.

Changed script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 1>>/tmp/rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync.log 2>&1
/usr/bin/docker exec -i mongodb mkdir /data/dump
/usr/bin/docker exec -i mongodb mongodump --db myDB -u theUser -p thePassword --gzip --out /data/dump/

# RClone Config file
RCLONE_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/.config/rclone/rclone.conf
export RCLONE_CONFIG
#if [[ "`pidof -x $(basename $0) -o %PPID`" ]]; then exit; fi

/usr/bin/rclone sync /data/dump/myDB/MongoDB_Backup:MongoDB_Current
```

Now, the script is able to run as intended, and runs automatically each hour. The fix was changing the `-it` in the `Docker` commands to just `-i`.

Comment: Remember you can accept your own answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Line four of your script looks suspicious, as confirmed by [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
% shellcheck rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync
In rclone_Linux_MongoDB_Sync line 4:
/usr/bin/docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --db dashboarddb -u hifi_dbpc_host ->
    ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this simple command.
    ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this redirection. Fix to allow more checks.
    ^-- SC1072: Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Comment: Apologies. It appears that while copy and pasting, there were some errors. The -> I believe was from cat, indicating that the line continues. I have now updated the code.

Comment: When I do run shellscript locally, there is nothing displayed